# Is there a python class library? If so where

Tags: python, helper

I know there is a java class library with all the classes, methods and information on them but I do not know if there is a python one. I'm new to python so I think there must be one and I just haven't heard of it. If anyone could direct me to one, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Asking for recommendations or references is *specifically* listed as off-topic.

Comment: @prune I don't see that this is either asking for recommendations or references. It is very specific and asks where you can find the "Python class library" by which is most likely meant The Python Standard Library. Specific and on point, as best you can do as a new user, and there is only one specific answer. Very basic question, yes, but since it's asked, the one who asks actually needs an answer to this.

Comment: That is *exactly* asking for a reference.  Also, "all the classes" is ambiguous: is this all Python built-in classes, all commonly used classes (opinion), or all existing classes?  I've seen requests for all three on this site.

Comment: @Prune Can you refer to the exact place where the word "reference" is used in the rules, so we can investigate further in what sense it is meant? I did not find it anywhere in the links you listed. I still find the question useful and relevant (and no, I did *not* read it as asking for "all commonly used classes" or any sort of opinion), so I am surprised if such a question is not allowed and would like to read that first-hand from the written rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [The Python Standard Library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

It's not called the "Python class library", as unlike Java, not everything in Python has to be a class.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that it's not called the "Python class library" because unlike Java, not everything in Python has to be in a class.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the suggestion! I added it.